# When defining sbt submodules, is it possible to define dependency as "compile->test"

Tags: scala, sbt

Here is my situation:

module-core has a test, which has some logic that I would like to share with another project

What I'd like to do:

Create 2 modules: module-test-util and module-test, module-test would depend on module-test-util, and module-test-util would depend on module-core.

In order for external project to use module-test-util, its "Util" traits would have to be in "compile" scope, not in "test" scope, so I'm trying to define dependencies like this:

```
module-test-util.dependsOn(module-core % "compile->test")
module-test.dependsOn(module-test-util % "test->compile")
```

But this is not working, my module-test-util does not pick up dependencies from module-core, neither from test scope, nor from compile scope.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Something else was wrong with my project setup, I did get it working after all with above configuration.